# How can i open/browse html inside c# code?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to create a visual program using C# window form app so I would like to ask how can I browse or open a local html document that i created which is located on my desktop using C# VS?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
Process.Start(urlToOpen);
```

or add `WebBrowser` in your form then load the `url` or `file path`.

And in your `Form Load Event`

```
webBrowser1.Url = new Uri("filepath or url");
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the "WebBrowser" control on a form or usercontrol to achieve this.

It should exist in your "Toolbox", categorized under "Common Controls".  You will drag and drop it onto your Form or UserControl tabbed window - during design mode (note the *[Design]* in the tab text and visual display).

[image: WebBrowser Control in Toolbox]

you can review more information on the control [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/webbrowser-control-windows-forms)

the class documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser?view=netframework-4.8), which provides an example of it's usage.